# Echo and Wink, how to send a TCP packet to device on local network?

Tags: smart-home, wink-hub

I am looking to create voice control for my stereo receiver. Remote control of the receiver is fairly easy to do by sending specific TCP packets to its IP address.

However, I'm having trouble connecting the dots for what would communicate with the receiver.

- I know with the Echo, the custom skill type is a no go since that runs code in AWS (so wouldn't be able to get to my local network without some workarounds).
- Then I assumed something with the Wink *should* be able to do this, since it controls local devices, but now I'm thinking that is all done with bluetooth, Z-Wave, etc... i.e. not over a computer network.

So am I left with a Raspberry Pi or something like that?

**EDIT:**
This question came about because I'm always inclined to DIY things, but I suppose the easiest solution is an Echo + Harmony Hub.

Comment: The Echo only supports local traffic for specific officially endorsed devices, though there have been writeups on how to impersonate those.  In terms of doing something with a pi, the question is so open-ended as to be unanswerably broad.  Typically the way cloud-agent systems want you to do it is for your controllable device to have its own cloud service that their server pushes requests to, and then your controllable devices get downlink commands from your server by a mechanism such as MQTT subscriptions where they establish and an outgoing channel down which incoming requests can be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring my mentioning of using a Wink... [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075258/how-can-i-access-a-local-api-using-amazon-alexa) in SO is basically what I was after. It has two good answers:

- The skill's lambda would send messages to an SQS queue that something on my local network subscribes to. That client would then forward commands to the stereo receiver.
- Use AWS IoT... I think a similar concept to the first bullet, just more of a managed solution.

Comment: If you want a ready rolled solution that you can modify you can use Node-RED and the Alexa Smart Home Skill node (I wrote the node http://alexa-node-red.bm.hardill.me.uk/)